# Taking advantage of hardware acceleration by using -webkit-transform instead of -webkit-transition?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I wish to create an animation where upon every click of a button, an object moves a certain amount to its right.

e.g If the initial position of the object was say "left:10px" and every 1 loop of animation moves it by say 10px, then after first click it should be at 20px, after second click it should be at 30px and so on.

Here's my code right now:

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById( 'move-me' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {

    var move = document.getElementById( 'move' );
    move.style.left = ( move.offsetLeft + 10 ) + 'px';

}, false );
```

HTML

```
<button id="move-me">Move</button>
<div id="move"></div>
```

CSS

```
#move {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transition:             left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:    left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:      left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: left 250ms ease-in-out;
    width: 50px;
}
```

This code uses CSS3 transitions but it doesn't make use of the -webkit-transform hardware acceleration on my android device. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The choice is not between `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transition`, it's between `left` and `-webkit-transform`.

Here is how to make use of 3d acceleration:

```
#move {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      -o-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition:             transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById( 'move' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    var move = document.getElementById( 'move' );
    var transform = "translate3d("+ (move.offsetLeft+200) + "px, 0, 0)";
    move.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    move.style.mozTransform = transform;
    move.style.msTransform = transform;
    move.style.oTransform = transform;
    move.style.transform = transform;

}, false );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CjQ8H/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use translateX. This defintely hardware accelerates.

```
targetDiv.style.webkitTransition = "0ms"

targetDiv.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(100%)
```

This would move a div to the right by 100% but nice and smooth only in hardware accelerated devices.